# Data persistency across installation on Android

Tags: java, android, android-storage

I want to give the user a free trial of my app. When the app first starts it needs to be checked if this trial has already been used up. My app is not account based and requires no online connection so I am hoping for an offline solution.

Is there any way to store data persistently on the Device even upon uninstallation apart from storing device IDs in a Database? Right now the trial starts with every reinstall so it definitely misses the point.

SharedPreferences and the keystore are not an option because the keys get deleted when uninstalling.

For keystore I used this very nice library [secure-storage-android.](https://github.com/adorsys/secure-storage-android/blob/master/LICENSE)

Comment: The only way you can sort of achieve this completely offline is by storing some data in an unconventional path (like a system subdirectory) that won't be removed when the app is uninstalled. But chances are you won't be able to write there on all Android devices, depending on permission implementations. Anyway, there is a [related post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158508/how-do-some-android-apps-remember-that-this-is-not-the-first-time-they-are-being) that enumerates other strategies than this, but they require an internet connection.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for your help. Not what I hoped for but what I anticipated :)